# Django Rest frameworks: request.Post vs request.data?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

The Django Rest Frameworks has this to say about `POST`, quoting a Django dev

> #### Requests
>
> If you're doing REST-based web service stuff ... you should ignore request.POST.
>
> — Malcom Tredinnick, Django developers group

As not-so experienced web-developer, why is `request.POST` (standard) discouraged over `request.DATA` (non-standard)? Is one more flexible?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The docs cover this:

> request.data returns the parsed content of the request body. This is similar to the standard request.POST and request.FILES attributes except that:
>
> - It includes all parsed content, including file and non-file inputs.
> - It supports parsing the content of HTTP methods other than POST, meaning that you can access the content of PUT and PATCH requests.
> - It supports REST framework's flexible request parsing, rather than just supporting form data. For example you can handle incoming JSON data in the same way that you handle incoming form data.

The last two are the important ones. By using `request.data` throughout instead of `request.POST`, you're supporting both JSON and Form-encoded inputs (or whatever set of parsers you have configured), and you'll be accepting request content on `PUT` and `PATCH` requests, as well as for `POST`.

> Is one more flexible?

Yes. `request.data` is more flexible.

Comment: And are those ( Form-encoded inputs ) important? Why do I need  the *content* of PUT and PATCH ? Doesn't DRF handle that?

Comment: Django's `request.POST` *only* gives you support for POST requests with form encoded data. *If* you want to handle JSON, or *if* you want to make PUT and PATCH requests, then REST framework's `request.data` is what you want, yes.

Answer (score 10):

I think some users get redirected here when trying to get data from the POST body in vanilla Django (when they aren't using the Django REST framework). In case you're using a basic Django endpoint you use `request.body` to get data from the body of the request so long as it isn't form data that's being sent to the server (in that case use `request.POST`). This is different from the `request.data` attribute that is needed for accessing data with Django REST framework.

```
from json import loads
def login(request):
    json = loads(request.body)
    print(json['username']) # Prints the value associated with
```

`loads(request.body)` is needed because request.body returns a byte string. `loads` will convert that byte string into a dictionary.

`request.BODY`, `request.data`, and `request.DATA` are all undefined for Django's default request object.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/

Notice there is no `.data` attribute under HttpRequest which differs from the Django REST framework request.

(This doesn't answer the original question but might help users that end up here who aren't using the REST framework)

Comment: I appreciate this answer, but you don't link to a source.  Is this now in the docs?

Comment: Sorry, I just tested it on Django 2.2 and found that none of the properties other than `request.body` work. Went and found the docs just now, they're here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/

Comment: the question remains whether this change is reflected in the Django Rest Framework API.

Comment: I am quite sure the accepted answer is still correct - since this is about Django Rest Framework? `request.data` is still the correct way in DRF.

Comment: @AsmoSoinio Yep you are correct I'll change the answer thanks, sorry about that.