# Django best practice to get object from id in POST request

Tags: python, django

In my API, sometimes you make HTTP request with id of objects (like update preferred address you put the id of your new default address).

I retrieve it like this:

```
address = get_object_or_404(
    Address.objects.filter(...), 
    pk=request.data['address_pk']
)
```

This is completely functional, however it doesn't feel as the best way. I tried to search for the best practice, however I was not able to find proper search term which would satisfy my curiosity.

Is this way of getting a model instance from a request a good practice? Or should it be avoided?

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you need.

Comment: just to know if what I'm doing is a good practice or if I should avoid it.

Comment: `get_object_or_404(Address, pk=request.data['address_pk'])` that's it. Yes this is also recommended by Django, and mostly things varies up to the requirement, but for updateview or patch / put API this is enough, also in UpdateView you can completely restrict through queryset

Answer (score 0):

The common practice is to use the `request` object correctly. Not the `request.data`.

```
pk = request.POST.get('address_pk', 0)
address = get_object_or_404(Address, pk=pk)
```

You should ONLY use `request.POST` using the `get` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wondering if using request.data is the best option, answer to this question is comparing request.POST and request.DATA

[Compare request.POST and request.DATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545553/django-rest-frameworks-request-post-vs-request-data)

Answer (score 0):

```
pk=request.data['address_pk']
```

This will raise a `KeyError` if `address_pk` is not present in the request data. Later on, you'll find yourself writing a `try...except` block to handle it.

A shorter way would be to use the [`dict.get`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey) method.

```
request.data.get('address_pk') # this will default to None if key is absent
```

And the `KeyError` won't raise. This helps reduce 3-4 lines of code.

---

But this may not always be the best solution, because you might want to maybe send a `400 Bd Request` response when a particular key is absent from POST data. In that case, you'll have to write the `try...except` block for that.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one better approach for this can be.

Make URL something like this `http://domain.name/address/(?P<id>[0-9]{*})/` using URL Patterns in Django, which will have address ID in URL and can be passed to view as parameter called `id` and then you can use that to retrieve the Address in same way.